# CSS3 flip animation on hover and background change on non CSS3 browser

Tags: css

I want to animate (Flip) my GIF image on hover on CSS3 browser and on non CSS3 browser just change the background color.

i can achieve CSS3 Flip animation using code

```
.imageselector:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
}
```

and background change using

```
.imageselector:hover { background:#FFF999; }
```

i want to combine both so that in CSS3 supporting browser it should animate only and in non-CSS3 browser it should change background color only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, here's how I'd approach it:  Put the image into a container div that will change the background color when the hover fires.

```
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gv648iUY5p0/UD8rqW3deSI/AAAAAAAAACA/MrG4KxFyM5A/s72-c/Fish.jpeg" />
    </div>
```

Then, apply the CSS3 animation to the image.

```
    * {margin:0; padding:0;}
    .container {width:100px; height:100px; background:#cde; margin:20px;}
    .container img {padding:14px; display:block; -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;}
    .container:hover {background:#abc;}
    .container:hover img {-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);}
```

Browsers that support it will animate.  The rest will just change the background.  Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/xfnHr/

Comment: i want to display hover effect on a transparent image by animating image in CSS3 browsers and by changing background color in non-CSS3 supporting browsers (in CSS3 supporting browser it must not change background color).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with pure CSS.  I added some jQuery to handle the background: http://jsfiddle.net/xfnHr/1/